# Kafka state-store sharing across sub-toplogies

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to create a custom joining consumer to join multiple events.

I have created a topology which have four sub-toplogies(subtopology-0, subtoplogy-1, subtopology-2, subtopology-3) not in the exact order of what is described by topology.describe().

I have created a state-store in three of the sub-toplogies(subtopology-0, subtoplogy-1, subtopology-2) and trying to attach all the state-store created different state-stores using .connectProcessorAndStateStores("PROCESS2", "COUNTS") as per the kafka developer guide https://kafka.apache.org/0110/documentation/streams/developer-guide

Here is the code snippet of how I am creating and attaching processors to the topology.

```
class StreamCustomizer implements  KafkaStreamsInfrastructureCustomizer {
   public someMethod(StreamBuilder builder) {
    Topology topology = builder.build();

    topology.addProcessor("Processor1", new Processor() {...}, "state-store-1).addStateStore(store1,..);
    topology.addProcessor("Processor2", new Processor() {...}, "state-store-1)
.addStateStore(store1,..);
    topology.addProcessor("Processor3", new Processor() {...}, "state-store-1)
addStateStore(store1,..);
topology.addProcessor("Processor4", new Processor4() {...}, "Processor1", Processor2", "Processor3")
connectProcessorAndStateStores("Prcoessor4", "state-store-1", "state-store-2", "state-store-3");
  

}
}
```

This is how the processor is defined for all the sub-toplogies as described above

```
new Processor {
 private ProcessorContext;
private KeyValueStore<K, V> store;
  init(ProcessorContext) {
   this.context = context;
   store = context.getStore("store-name");
}
}
```

This is hot the processor 4 is written, with all the state-store retrieved in init method from context store.

```
new Processor4() {
private KeyValueStore<K, V> store1;
private KeyValueStore<K, V> store2;
private KeyValueStore<K, V> store3;
}
```

I am observing a strange behaviour that with the above code, store1, store2, and store3 all are re-intiailized and no keys are preserved whatever were stored in their respective sub-toplogies(1,2,3). **However, the same code works** i.e., all state store preserved the key-value stored in their respective sub-topology **when state-stores are declared at class level.**

```
class StreamCustomizer implements  KafkaStreamsInfrastructureCustomizer { 
 private KeyValueStore <K, V> store1;
 private KeyValueStore <K, V> store2;
 private KeyValueStore <K, V> store3;
}
```

and then in the processor implementation, just init the state-store in init method.

```
new Processor {
 private ProcessorContext;
  init(ProcessorContext) {
   this.context = context;
   store1 = context.getStore("store-name-1");
}
}
```

Can someone please assist in finding the reason, or if there is anything wrong in this topology? Also, I have read in state-store can be shared within the same sub-topology.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say (the code snippets are not really clear), however, if share state you effectively merge sub-topologies. Thus, if you do it correct, you would end up with a single sub-topology containing all your processor.

As long as you see 4 sub-topologies, state store are not shared yet, ie, not connected correctly.